# Preventing refresh within form javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to allow for a form to call a java script function without losing javascript dependent data on the page.

This is what I got.

The function is some generic appending function.

I lose of the appended data whenever I change the input string.

I added

```
        window.onbeforeunload = function(){
            return false;
        }
```

And it would work as long as I pressed no on all of the popup boxes.

Thank you

Edit: I ahve noticed that it happens wehenever the url name is changed

here is html for good measure

```
    <form method="get" action="#">
      <input type="text" id="data" name="post" placeholder="thoughts?" />
      <button onclick="appendToBody()">
        Post
      </button>
    </form>
```

Comment: can you provide html code also?

Comment: You need to use AJAX to send the form data to the server.

Comment: Not using any backend

Comment: The html code is just a div of the specified name, I am not sure how it is relevant!

Comment: I don't get it. Every time you reload you page submiting a form - you lose your javascript data - it's normall. Maybe you need `$('form').submit(function() {});`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

returning false in the forms onsubmit will stop the submit action.

```
  <form onsubmit="calltoyourfunction;return false">
```